# optional reference implementation

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem here where I am not sure how to handle it. Firstly I am beginner. I have two constructors for a class and two reference variables declared but I can not use both references in one constructor. If cons1() is called I need ref1 to be used and if cons2 is called I need ref2 to be used. The problem is in what should I reference ref1 to, when cons2 is called and similarly what ref2 should reference when cons1 is called. I am not sure how to initialize these references. It can't be NULL. I am not sure if its a good idea to point to some  invalid implementation. Should it? Is that even an option?  How is such a problem handled in c++?

```
// A.cpp
Class A
A(Object1& a) : ref1(a) {}   - here how should ref2 be handled?
A(Object2& b) : ref2(b) {}- here what should ref1 reference?

// A.h
Object1& ref1
Object2& ref2
```

I need to use references here. I understand we can use pointers instead of references but the question is specific to using references.

Comment: Can you improve on the question title? We know it's a question already because you posted it, and we know it's C++ because it's so tagged.

Comment: *"I need to use references here"* -- Why place arbitrary restrictions on yourself?  If it's really the case, then I'll vote to close as too localized.  If this is a real programming problem, we use the right tool for the job, we don't place arbitrary restrictions on ourselves.

Comment: Its not just a localized problem though the problem did arise in my personal work. The problem in general is how we handle such situations in c++. If using pointers in place of refs is the only solution then we can close it out saying thats the soln.

Comment: @leonidus It's not the only way, it's however a very idiomatic one.

Comment: Too localized for sure. The necessity to use references is purely arbitrary and not useful for general C++ programming.

Answer (score 6):

Since ref1 and ref2 are optional (not required), then it is better to use pointers, instead of references :

```
class A
{
  public:
    A(Object1& a) : ref1(&a), ref2(NULL) {}
    A(Object2& b) : ref1(NULL),ref2(&b) {}

 Object1 *ref1;
 Object2 *ref2;
};
```

but later you must check if the ref1 and ref2 are NULL.

Comment: This answer is correct. Still, it seems like a poor approach to take in code.

Comment: @Tomalak Why? I guess you could use boost::optional

Comment: Because the object is being given wildly different semantics based on nothing more than the type of a constructor argument. You have to be really careful that there are no implicit conversions between `Object1` and `Object2` or you'll get unexpected behaviour, and in every function in `A` you're going to have to check which is used and duplicate code all over the place depending on which it is. Depending on the wider use case, an interface-style base class and two derived class variants would probably make far more sense.

Comment: @OP: you could also use dummy objects in the same way linked lists uses a "sentinel node"

Comment: Assume that I need to use references here.

Comment: @leonidus: You don't, a pointer is fine. If you can't use a pointer, then this question is too localized.

Comment: @Tomalak All correct, but the question gives very little information what exactly should be done. Maybe the two classes you are proposing don't event need a common base class. Anyway, you got away into discussion about computer engineering (“sanely structuring software”)

Comment: @VJo: This question is about sanely structuring the OP's software.

Comment: @DeadMG: I know I can use pointers. Anyway how does it matter if its too localized or not. Thats not what I intend to discuss anyway. I am trying to understand the c++ way of doing things. Being from Java world just starting to learn the c++ semantics.

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING:** the following is stupid and contrived. Why? Because so is the requirement to use references.

```
class base {
    virtual
    ~base();

    virtual
    void
    stuff_happens() = 0;
};
base::~base() = default;

class case1: public base {
public:
    explicit
    case1(Object1& o)
        : ref(o)
    {}

    void
    stuff_happens()
    {
        // we use ref here
    }

private:
    Object1& ref;
};

class case2: public base {
public:
    explicit
    case2(Object2& o)
        : ref(o)
    {}

    void
    stuff_happens()
    {
        // we use ref here
    }

private:
    Object2& ref;
};

std::unique_ptr<base>
make_base(Object1& o)
{ return std::unique_ptr<base>(new case1(o)); }

std::unique_ptr<base>
make_base(Object2& o)
{ return std::unique_ptr<base>(new case2(o)); }

// ...
{
    auto p = condition ? make_base(ref1) : make_base(ref2);
    p->stuff_happens();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer has already been given: switch to pointers.  References in this case provide zero benefit, and as you have seen have a huge downside.  Your design is dubious to begin with; let's not complicate things by introducing additional bad requirements.

However, if you insist on using references, the only possible solution is to introduce a sentinel value of some sort.

```
struct A {
    A(Object1& o) : obj1(o), obj2(null2) { }
    A(Object2& o) : obj1(null1), obj2(o) { }

    void function() { 
        if(&obj1 == &null1)
            //Object2 constructor
        else
            //Object1 constructor
    }

  private:
    Object1& obj1;
    Object2& obj2;

    static Object1 null1;
    static Object2 null2;
};

//implementation file
Object1 A::null1;
Object2 A::null2;
```

This method depends on `Object1` and `Object2` both having default constructors, or otherwise having a sensible default value for the sentinels.  `null1` and `null2` will both exist for the entire life of the application, so if they acquire any resources, you will essentially have a leak.

You also have to be a lot more careful with invalid uses of the sentinels, because such access is [in the general case] perfectly safe.  A strong argument can be made that it is better for bugs to result in undefined behavior that is likely to crash, than for them to result in well defined behavior that is likely to simply produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have NULL values, you should switch from a reference to a pointer. Some compilers support NULL references, but this is bad style and not portable and should therefore be avoided.

Comment: All compilers support NULL reference. The problem is - it is an UB to dereference a NULL reference object.

Comment: What compilers? By definition a reference (in C++) **can't** be NULL

Comment: @VJo: "All compilers support NULL reference"?! No. It's UB to dereference a NULL pointer, and you cannot obtain a NULL reference any other way. So the UB occurs _before_ this mythical NULL reference support could ever come into play. (And what does it mean to dereference a reference, exactly?)

Comment: @dragonwrenn: Don't use deprecated headers. That's `cstdlib` in C++. Also, read [this](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/fncpp/NullOrZero).

Comment: @Tomalak I am sure you can find in many questions here. Like this : `int *p=NULL;int &r=(*p);` As long as you don't use variable `r` it is ok

Comment: @VJo: No. As I said before, as soon as you perform `*p`, all bets are off (2003: 1.9/4). 2003: 8.3.2/4 makes this exact fact explicit in a non-normative note which reads: "in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only
way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior."

Comment: @Tomalak Ok, I see. But all compilers (that I know), are implementing references as pointers, therefore the above be fine, as long as you don't really use the reference.

Comment: @VJo: No. Even those compilers are free to blow up in your face. Just _don't do it_, and certainly don't teach it.